# Why $(a,b)\mid a+b\le3$ is not reflexive and is symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, relations

Why $(a,b)\mid a+b\le3$ is not reflexive and is symmetric?

I read because a€ Z so by counter example
$(5,5)$, $5+5$ is not less than or equal to $3$
So it's not reflexive

But why it's symmetric ? 
I think because for all a,b €Z
So $3+4$ is not less than or equal to $3$
So it is not symmitric

Comment: Definitely it is symmetric.

Comment: After three such questions, I suspect trolling ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symmetry does't require that every pair of integers be related.

Symmetry requires ONLY that **IF** $(a, b)\in R$, **THEN** $(b, a)\in R$.

We have an implication defining symmetry: $\quad p: (a, b)\in R;\quad q: (b, a) \in R$
where $$p \rightarrow q$$

If $(a, b) \notin R$, that's fine. If our premise $p$ is false, the implication is automatically true. So your example of $3$ and $4$ doesn't present a problem, since $(3, 4)\notin R$.  It is only for those pairs $(x, y)\in R$ that **are** related that we have to ensure that $(y, x)$ is also in the relation.

Comment: But the definition of symmetric is "(b,a) € R whenever (a,b) € R , FOR ALL a,b €A

Comment: That's right, and "whenever" here translates logically as "IF": For all $a, b$, **If** $(a, b)\in R$, **then** $(b, a) \in R$:  $$\forall a, b \in A\Big((a, b)\in R \rightarrow (b, a) \in R\Big)$$

Comment: @amWhy: Nice that you clarify such things for OPs +1

Answer (score 2):

It is symmetric if for all $a,b$, $$a + b \leq 3 \Leftrightarrow  b + a \leq 3$$

Proving whether or not is symmetric in this case boils down to determining whether $b + a \leq 3$ if you know $a + b \leq 3$ (and vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric means if $aRb$, then $bRa$, which is the case here.